# Defining Schema.org JSON-LD for my Multi-language Web application

Tags: schema.org, microdata, json-ld

I am building a web application for product comparison. The website has a structure like so:

```
http://example.com
http://example.com/fr/compare/
http://example.com/es/compare/
```

etc..

The main page is in English.

I want to insert Schema.org for each of the pages and I've construed this schema. Written in square brackets are what I intend to put as value later on.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@id": "[canonical-url-for-specific-language]#webapp",
  "@type": "WebApplication",
  "name": "[Product Comparison Title in specific language]",
  "url": "[canonica url for specific language]",
  "applicationCategory": "Utility",
  "applicationSubCategory": "Product Comparison",    
  "about": "[page-description]",
  "browserRequirements": "Requires JavaScript. Requires HTML5.",
  "softwareVersion": "1.0.0",
  "screenshot": "[image-url]",
  "inLanguage": "[language-code]",
  "softwareHelp": {
    "@type": "CreativeWork",
      "url": "[link-to-how-to-page-for-specific-language]"
  },
  "operatingSystem": "All"
}
</script>
```

How can I construct this JSON-LD well to work for my specific website.

Comment: You seem to have three questions that shouldn’t be in the same question post: 1) Should the Schema.org properties `workTranslation` and `translationOfWork` be used when already using the HTML attribute `hreflang`? 2) Should values of `applicationCategory` and `applicationSubCategory` be translated? 3) What to improve (?)/change (?) in my JSON-LD? -- I would suggest to [edit] your post to make it about one question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use structured data for a home page that has a language selector, then the markup can be similar to the following:

```js
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@id": "[canonical-url-for-specific-language]#webapp",
  "@type": "WebApplication",
  "name": "[Product Comparison Title in specific language]",
  "url": "[canonica url for specific language]",
  "applicationCategory": "Utility",
  "applicationSubCategory": "Product Comparison",    
  "about": "[page-description]",
  "browserRequirements": "Requires JavaScript. Requires HTML5.",
  "softwareVersion": "1.0.0",
  "screenshot": "[image-url]",
  "inLanguage":[{
      "@type": "Language",
      "name": "English",
      "alternateName": "en",
      "additionalType":"https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php",
      "sameAs":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Language",
      "name": "Spanish",
      "alternateName": "es",
      "additionalType":"https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php",
      "sameAs":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_language"
    }],
  "softwareHelp": {
    "@type": "CreativeWork",
      "name":"Customer Service and Support",
      "url": [
      "https://examples.com/en/help.html",
      "https://examples.com/es/help.html"
      ]
  },
  "operatingSystem": "All"
}
```

Note that I have here used for each language two identifiers with the properties **sameAs** and **additionalType**.

If the web page is with one particular language, then just delete the part of the markup for the unnecessary language and the square brackets.

Check out this markup on the **[Google testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)** and note that there are two warnings that are useful to fix.

Comment: Are you sure that inLanguage can contain anything else than an iso code? The schema.org definition is pretty clear: https://schema.org/Language